# Flutter / how can i set border to container like samsung one ui app icon

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to set the border of the container, something similar to the photo below

[image]

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)

Comment: Can you click on [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73355375/edit) and include your snippet

Comment: This look like Samsung experience app icon. Not achivable with border radius. You need to write customPaint with arch's or find PNG icon and Mask it with shader @Hamed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find png of that icon and give it's path to mask parameter and give your Image widget to image parameter.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MaskedImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget image;
  final String mask;
  final BoxFit fit;

  const MaskedImage({
    Key? key,
    required this.image,
    required this.mask,
    this.fit = BoxFit.cover,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        return FutureBuilder<List>(
          future: _createShaderAndImage(
            image,
            mask,
            constraints.maxWidth,
            constraints.maxHeight,
          ),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const SizedBox.shrink();
            return ShaderMask(
              blendMode: BlendMode.dstATop,
              shaderCallback: (rect) => snapshot.data![0],
              child: snapshot.data![1],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<List> _createShaderAndImage(
    Widget image,
    String mask,
    double w,
    double h,
  ) async {
    ByteData maskData = await rootBundle.load(mask);

    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(
      maskData.buffer.asUint8List(),
      targetWidth: w.toInt(),
      targetHeight: h.toInt(),
      allowUpscaling: false,
    );
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();

    ImageShader shader = ImageShader(
      fi.image,
      TileMode.clamp,
      TileMode.clamp,
      Matrix4.identity().storage,
      filterQuality: ui.FilterQuality.high,
    );
    return [shader, image];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the ratio of circular border is  4. try to modify if needed.

```dart
 Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100 * .4),
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
),
```

[image]

Also, height is little increased on your attached image, modify it the way like

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100 * .4),
  color: Colors.green,
 ),
 width: 100,
 height: 100,
 child: const Icon(
  Icons.phone,
  size:50,
  color:Colors.white,
 ),
),
```

That's all u can use like this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVTAL.png)